# Index iterator -

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, iterator

```
random_names = [names[random.randint(low=0,high=len(names))] for i in range(1000)]
```

can some explain this code, especially how the for loops works and the argument {random.randint(low=0,high=1000)} that comes before it ?

Usually there's a list and we iterate over it but here it iterates the index,names[n] before the for loop.

Comment: This code has a bug; that `randint` call could return `len(names)`, which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Complex one-liners like this are hard to read, so it helps to break them out. The listcomp is exactly equivalent to this code:

```
random_names = []
for i in range(1000):
    random_index = random.randint(low=0,high=len(names))
    random_names.append(names[random_index])
```

So for each of 1000 iterations, a new random index is generated, and the value corresponding that index of `names` is added to `random_names`.